# Using Delay within ConcatMap, Observable only emits once

Tags: rxjs

Given the following code:

```js
range(1, 30)
  .pipe(
    windowCount(10),
    concatMap(x => x.pipe(delay(5000))),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

For some reason only the first value is emitted (1..10), could anyone please point out what's wrong with the above code? Thanks.

expected output: 1..10 (delay) 11..20 (delay) and so on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `windowCount` will complete the previous inner "window" before creating a new one. You delay each "window" by 5s but when `concatMap` wants to subscribe to the next "window" it has completed already and will never ever emit anything.

Note, that `windowCount` will emit all windows asap regardless whether `concatMap` had even chance to subscribe to them.

Comment: Doesn't `ConcatMap` "remembers" the next observable although it does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous completes?

Comment: It does keep a buffer of all source values it has received. But the buffered Observables are in fact Subjects that have already been completed. So `concatMap` tries to sibscribe to them but nothing happens https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L129

Comment: instead of `windowCount ` what if you use `bufferCount` ?

Comment: yeah, `bufferCount` uses just arrays internally or you can use `scan` as well.

Comment: What is the reason `windowCount` has been completed? what causes this behavior?

Comment: If it didn't complete it there would be no way to complete it. That's how it's implemented https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/windowCount. If it didn't complete it wouldn't work with `concatMap` anyway because it waits until the inner Observable completes.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using [bufferCount](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferCount) and expected output is achieved.

```
range(1, 30)
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(10),
    concatMap(x => x.pipe(delay(5000))),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bufferwithdelay-nyks)**

Comment: I wanted to understand this specific behavior, thank your for your answer! I've upvoted your answer